# iPhone keeps going into dim/sleep mode even with the proper API calls

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I call:

[[ UIApplication sharedApplication ] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES ]

on the applicationDidFinishLaunching event.. I set a breakpoint on it, which fires so I know it's getting called.. I've also called this function in other places as well..  Basically, a 3G iPhone will still go into sleep mode, but my 3GS won't.  Has anyone seen this behavior before?  Both are running the latest OS versions.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Just to let everyone know, this is a confirmed bug in the OS.  I rebooted the phone and now it behaves fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting the 3G iPhone will fix the issue.  I am not sure if Apple is working on a fix for this currently.